# Group Datasets and take minimum/maximum

Tags: list-manipulation, dataset, gathering

Good Morning

I have the following dataset:

[image: Input]

And I try to reach this output:

[image: Output]

- key: only one row per key
- text: join all texts of the rows with the same key (but no duplicates)
- min: take the lowest value (but not empty) of the rows with the same key
- max: take the highest value (but not empty) of the rows with the same key

I used `dataInput[GroupBy[{#key} &]]` but then I got stuck.
I tried to apply `Union`,`Max` and `Min` for individual rows but somehow I don't manage to generalize it.

Other attempts:

- `dataInput[GroupBy[#key &], MaximalBy[#max &]&&MinimalBy[#min&] // Values // Flatten`
- `Query[GroupBy["key"], Catenate, "text"] @ dataInput`
- `JoinAcross[dataInput, Key[key], "Inner", 
  KeyCollisionFunction -> Function[x, Max[x]]]`

Comment: Would help for you to post your dataset code as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
dataset = Dataset[{
   <|"key" -> "abc", "text" -> "h", "min" -> 1, "max" -> 5|>,
   <|"key" -> "abc", "text" -> "a", "min" -> 1, "max" -> 5|>,
   <|"key" -> "aaa", "text" -> "h", "min" -> 2, "max" -> 3|>,
   <|"key" -> "aaa", "text" -> "e", "min" -> 2, "max" -> 4|>,
   <|"key" -> "aaa", "text" -> "a", "min" -> 1|>,
   <|"key" -> "aaa", "text" -> "a", "max" -> 4|>}]
```

[image]

```
dataset2 = Merge[#, DeleteDuplicates] & /@ Values[GroupBy[dataset, Key["key"]]]
```

[image]

```
dataset2[All, {"key" -> First, "min" -> Min, "max" -> Max}]
```

[image]

Comment: It should really be as simple as `dataset[GroupBy["key"],Merge[{"text"->DeleteDuplicates,"min" -> Min, "max" -> Max}]]`. Hope `Merge` will be improved in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Given:

```
dataset = Dataset[{
   <|"key" -> "abc", "text" -> "h", "min" -> 1, "max" -> 5|>,
   <|"key" -> "abc", "text" -> "a", "min" -> 1, "max" -> 5|>,
   <|"key" -> "aaa", "text" -> "h", "min" -> 2, "max" -> 3|>,
   <|"key" -> "aaa", "text" -> "e", "min" -> 2, "max" -> 4|>,
   <|"key" -> "aaa", "text" -> "a", "min" -> 1|>,
   <|"key" -> "aaa", "text" -> "a", "max" -> 4|>}];
```

Then the following examples will work in *Mathematica* 10.1 and later:

```
dataset[
  GroupBy["key"] /* Values
, Transpose /* Query[{"key" -> First, "min" -> Min, "max" -> Max}]
]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

```
dataset[
  GroupBy["key"] /* Values
, <| "key" -> First /* "key"
   , "text" -> Query[All, "text"]
   , "min" -> Query[Min, "min"]
   , "max" -> Query[Max, "max"]
   |>
]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

This second form is less concise, but allows for more general transformations such as renaming columns, introducing new columns that were not present in the source data, or computing values that are dependent upon multiple source columns.